# How to get ViSimulator plugin to work in Notepad++ 7.6.6?

Tags: notepad++, plugins

I recently updated Notepad++ to version 7.6.6 and now my ViSimulator plugin (which provides VIM-style keybindings) won't work.  In fact, the Notepad++ plugin manager no longer recognizes ViSimulator at all.

I re-downloaded the DLL visimulator.dll [here](https://github.com/bycn82/visimulator) and saved it to my plugins folder but the Notepad++ Plugins Admin panel doesn't see it.  I am using the 32 bit version of Notepad++.

Has anyone experienced this issue and figured out a solution?  Thanks!

Comment: The URL seems to be missing, but I found another user having it uploaded here https://github.com/windxuemo/visimulator

Answer (score 2):

- Create a directory `ViSimulator` in your `plugins` directory
- Make sure you copy your `ViSimulator.dll` into that directory not at the `plugins` directory level (that's changed from previous versions!)
- Start up `NotePad++`
- Look at `Plugins` dropdown - ViSimulator should now show up
- Select it and make sure you Enable the plugin

It should work now. I just did this a minute ago after scrambling about after a NP++ version update and my previous Vi mode no longer worked.